# MySQL updating data in a column using a loop

Tags: mysql, loops, procedure

I created a little program to show my students how to use loops in MySQL (Workbench).

The program updates a column in a table with test data.  I want to add a range of interest rates. When I run the program, the same interested rate is entered into each row.

```
CREATE TABLE  mtgPayment
  (lengthMonths DECIMAL(4,0),
  mInterest DECIMAL(8,6),
  loanAmt DECIMAL(10,2));

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_data()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i DECIMAL(8,6) DEFAULT 2.0;

  WHILE i < 3.5 DO
    UPDATE mtgpayment set mINTEREST = i;
    SET i = i + .5;
  END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL test_data();

SELECT * FROM mtgpayment;
```

Comment: You have no `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` query, so it's updating all rows each time through the loop.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `INSERT` rather than `UPDATE`?